# Experience with MonoTorrent or alternative to use BitTorrent on C#

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent, libtorrent, monotorrent

I've been using the MonoTorrent library for a couple of weeks now and am looking for any kind of feedback or recommended alternatives.

The only issue I have with the library so far is that it is MUCH slower than uTorrent, I am not sure if this is a configuration issue or whether it doesnt support a required feature etc, but I require higher speeds for my needs and I found that for the exact same file I can get a major difference (times 100) in terms of the numbers of seeders and speeds.

I wanted to give libtorrent a try as well but have not been able to even compile the windows dll, let alone write the required code to use it :-)

I probably don't know much about the history of the torrent protocol but found it strange to find so little support in the C#/.Net world.

Was even considering wrapping the uTorrent client somehow, but it might be 'frowned upon' lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using the libtorrent C++ library (running on a seperate process with added REST api to communicate with the main program) it works well and the torrent performance is excellent.

Comment: Uri, any chance you might make your implementation available? You're not the only one who would love a C#-oriented solution for libtorrent